# Is it safe to rely on condition evaluation order in if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

Is it bad practice to use the following format when `my_var` can be None?

```
if my_var and 'something' in my_var:
    #do something
```

*The issue is that `'something' in my_var` will throw a TypeError if my_var is None.*

Or should I use:

```
if my_var:
    if 'something' in my_var:
        #do something
```

or

```
try:
    if 'something' in my_var:
        #do something
except TypeError:
    pass
```

To rephrase the question, which of the above is the best practice in Python (if any)?

Alternatives are welcome!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It's safe to depend on the order of conditionals ([Python reference here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)), specifically because of the problem you point out - it's very useful to be able to short-circuit evaluation that could cause problems in a string of conditionals.

This sort of code pops up in most languages:

```
IF exists(variable) AND variable.doSomething()
    THEN ...
```

Comment: When I see code like the second, I assume the coder didn't understand how short-circuit evaluation works.

Comment: -1: No quote from the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: @cfi: Since I can change my vote after the answer changes, I'm unclear on what the problem is.

Comment: @cfi: Do whatever you think is most valuable to others.  My -1 on the comment is **unrelated** to my actual vote.  Interestingly, that allows one to make a lasting remark unrelated to the actual value of the response.

Comment: for everyone who is being negative, this is a valid question and isn't the same for every language.  VB will evaluate both unless you use  `andalso` or `orelse`

Comment: @blindguy Hows does C do it?

Answer (score 42):

Yes it is safe, it's explicitly and  very clearly defined in the language reference:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates
>   `x`; if `x` is `false`, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated
>   and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates
>   `x`; if `x` is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated
>   and the resulting value is returned.

Comment: Weak: it isn't "safe" -- it's absolutely required to depend on the order.

Answer (score 4):

I may be being a little pedantic here, but I would say the best answer is

```
if my_var is not None and 'something' in my_var:
    #do something
```

The difference being the explicit check for `None`, rather than the implicit conversion of `my_var` to `True` or `False`.

While I'm sure in your case the distinction isn't important, in the more general case it would be quite possible for the variable to not be `None` but still evaluate to `False`, for example an integer value of `0` or an empty list.

So contrary to most of the other posters' assertions that it's safe, I'd say that it's safe as long as you're explicit. If you're not convinced then consider this very contrived class:

```
class Contrived(object):
    def __contains__(self, s):
        return True
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False

my_var = Contrived()
if 'something' in my_var:
    print "Yes the condition is true"
if my_var and 'something' in my_var:
    print "But this statement won't get reached."
if my_var is not None and 'something' in my_var:
    print "Whereas this one will."
```

Yes I know that's not a realistic example, but variations do happen in real code, especially when `None` is used to indicate a default function argument.

Comment: surely, if you have an empty list or any container, for that matter, doing the `in` operation is meaningless. I think OP has it exactly right. while it's possible to construct anything to prove one's point, I don't believe that any decent code should shoot itself in the foot.

Comment: Yes, it's a contrived example, but my main point is that it's easy to get into the bad habit of saying '`if var`' when you really mean '`if var is not None`'. Once you get into that habit it can easily bite you, particularly with defaulted arguments.

Comment: I think it's quite clear that OP's intention was to say `if var` and that's what he did.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that simple. As a C# dude I am very used to doing something like:

```
if(x != null && ! string.isnullorempty(x.Name))
{
   //do something
}
```

The above works great and is evaluated as expected. However in VB.Net the following would produce a result you were NOT expecting:

```
If Not x Is Nothing **And** Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) Then

   'do something

End If
```

The above will generate an exception. The correct syntax should be

```
If Not x Is Nothing **AndAlso** Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) Then

   'do something

End If
```

Note the very subtle difference. This had me confused for about 10 minutes (way too long) and is why C# (and other) dudes needs to be very careful when coding in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the try/except, but it depends on what you know about the variable.

If you are expecting that the variable will exist most of the time, then a try/except is less operations.  If you are expecting the variable to be None most of the time, then an IF statement will be less operations.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly safe and I do it all the time.