# Pandas order of operation in & and | conditionals in short circuit evaluation

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, subset, evaluation

[Is it safe to rely on condition evaluation order in if statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752373/is-it-safe-to-rely-on-condition-evaluation-order-in-if-statements)

The above question asks exactly what I would like to know but is the same true of Pandas & and | operator when performing conditional selection.

Thankyou.

Edit: So this behaviour does not occur with pandas but is there any way one can achieve it?

Comment: No: `&` and `|` do *not* short-circuit, since you simply call a function behind the curtains with the two operands evaluated. Of course Numpy/pandas/... can implement this function in a "lazy-functional" way, but if there is no logic around this, it thus does not shortcircuit. Note that `&` and `|` do *not* per se work with booleans: one can return any kind of value.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: That is exactly what I wanted to know, thanks. You mentioned a lazy-functional workaround. Could you elaborate?

Comment: (particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22647040/2285236))

Comment: @JakeDyson: see it like this: you can make a function `sum(..)` that for a given collection calculates the sum, but you can also return an *object* that acts as a *postponed* operation, so `sum(my_tuple)` does *not* calculate the sum, it simply returns an object that in case you *need* to know the sum, it will calculate it.

Comment: See for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

Comment: Thankyou for your help, apologies for the duplicate @ayhan.